# Vue.jsの子コンポーネントのpropsのテスト

Tags: vue.js, テスト

Vue.jsのコンポーネントの単体テスト（Vue Test Utils）で、テストしているコンポーネントから子コンポーネントに、想定通りのpropsが渡っているかテストしたいのですが、どのように書けばいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@vue/test-utils`のmount (もしくはshallowMount) メソッドを用いてコンポーネントをマウントした場合、`wrapper.find(Child).props("prop")`のようにして子コンポーネントに渡されたpropsを取得することができます。

テスト全体は以下のようになるでしょう。

```js
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import App from "./App.vue";
import Child from "./components/Child.vue";

const wrapper = mount(App);

expect(wrapper.find(Child).props("fuga")).toEqual("hoge");
```

codesandboxでの例を以下に示します。

https://codesandbox.io/s/get-child-component-props-tieh9